# Cleanest way to express the exclusive or

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

One way to express the XOR using only AND, OR, NOT is:

¬(∧)∧¬(¬∧¬)

Is this the "cleanest" or most straightforward way to do it, or is there a simpler way to express the XOR relationship?

Comment: That expresses XOR using just AND & NOT.  You may use deMorgan's rules to express it with OR as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes, the description "either but not both" in the form $(A \vee B) \wedge \neg (A \wedge B)$ can be easier to parse (and is slightly shorter).

Answer (score 2):

Another way is $$(A \land \lnot B) \lor (\lnot A \land B)$$